# Lighting system

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been working on my new lighting system, at the moment it works really good but it has some bugs and color blending doesn't work as I want. Do you know some tricks to improve my code?
the drawing system is based on pixel.

```
    this.draw = function(data, w, h)
    {
        var r = Math.floor(this.radius), ra = r * r;
        var x = Math.floor(this.xCord), y = Math.floor(this.yCord);

        // Bounds
        var x0 = x - r;
        if(x0 < 0) x0 = 0;
        var x1 = x + r;
        if(x1 > w) x1 = w;
        var y0 = y - r;
        if(y0 < 0) y0 = 0;
        var y1 = y + r;
        if(y1 > h) y1 = h;

        // Color
        var c = this.colorLight;
        var rr = this.red,
            gg = this.green, 
            bb = this.blue;

        for (var yy = y0; yy < y1; yy++)
        {
            var yp = (yy - y0) - r, yt = yp * yp;
            var yw = yy * w;
            for (var xx = x0; xx < x1; xx++) 
            {
                var xp = (xx - x0) - r;
                var i = (xx + yw) * 4;
                d = (xp * xp) + yt;
                if(d <= ra)
                {
                    il = 1 - (d / ra);
                    data[i + 0] += ((rr + data[i + 0])) * il;
                    data[i + 1] += ((gg + data[i + 1])) * il;
                    data[i + 2] += ((bb + data[i + 2])) * il;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

preview: http://codepen.io/LukasHaring/pen/yNgERY

Comment: [What you may and may not do after recieving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you updated your code since you got the first response. The variable names are certainly an improvement over single-character names, but could still use some work.

```
this.draw = function(data, w, h)
```

What is `data`? That's way too general of a name to be useful. From looking at the code, it seems like it's the pixel buffer. Why not call it `pixels` or something more meaningful? Also, just expand `w` and `h` to `width` and `height`.

```
{
    var radius = Math.floor(this.radius), radiusPow = radius * radius;
    var x = Math.floor(this.xCord), y = Math.floor(this.yCord);
```

What are `xCord` and `yCord`? Are they the center of the light's location? Why not call them `xCenter` and `yCenter`? Also, my Javascript is really rusty. Can you have structures? If so, why not have a `Point` structure (or class) which contains an `x` and `y` member and manipulate that? It will be easier to read.

```
    // Bounds
    var x0 = x - radius;
    if(x0 < 0) x0 = 0;
    var x1 = x + radius;
    if(x1 > w) x1 = w;
    var y0 = y - radius;
    if(y0 < 0) y0 = 0;
    var y1 = y + radius;
    if(y1 > h) y1 = h;
```

You've repeated some code here 4 times. When you find yourself repeating code, it's probably best to break it out into a function. I'd make a `clamp` function, like this:

```
clamp (value, min, max)
{
    if (value < min)
    { 
        value = min;
    }
    if (value > max)
    {
        value = max;
    }
    return value;
}
```

(Sorry if my syntax is off, but I think you get the idea.) Then the above variable declarations can look like this:

```
    // Bounds
    var x0 = clamp (x - radius, 0, w);
    var x1 = clamp (x + radius, 0, w);
    var y0 = clamp (y - radius, 0, h);
    var y1 = clamp (y + radius, 0, h);
```

And why not pick better names for those, too? How about `xMin`, `xMax`, `yMin`, and `yMax`? It will make the loop below clearer, too.

This looks fine:

```
    // Color
    var c = this.colorLight;
    var red = this.red,
        green = this.green, 
        blue = this.blue;
```

This loop could still use some better naming:

```
    for (var j = y0; j < y1; j++)
    {
        var yp = (j - y0) - radius , yt = yp * yp;
        var yw = yy * w;
        for (var i = x0; i < x1; i++) 
        {
            var xp = (i - x0) - radius;
```

Rather than `i` and `j`, why not `column` and `row`, since you're iterating over rows and columns of pixels?

What do `yp`, `yt` and `yw` represent? It looks like `yp` is supposed to be the vertical distance from the center. I would think using `j - yCenter` would be a more direct way of calculating that. And I would call it `yDistance` or something like that. `yt` is obviously the square of `yp` which is fine for seeing if we're within the radius of the light's circle. Note that you can't directly using it for calculating the light's intensity if you're looking for realistic lighting, though. I don't understand what `yw` is at all. In fact, I don't see `yy` declared anywhere, so I don't see how this code works. Perhaps it was a transcription error?

Next, you have this:

```
            var i = (i + yw) * 4;
```

Oops! You already have a variable named `i`! The loop counter! This won't work.

This is fine for calculating if you're in the circle's radius:

```
            d = (xp * xp) + yt;
            if(d <= radiusPow)
            {
```

But this:

```
                il = 1 - (d / radiusPow);
```

does not give you the actual distance from the center (or its inverse). For that, you need to take the square root of `d` and divide it by `radius`. So it should probably be:

```
                il = 1 - (Math.sqrt(d) / radius);
```

I see 2 things that I'd do differently with this, if possible:

```
                data[i + 0] += ((red   + data[i + 0])) * il;
                data[i + 1] += ((green + data[i + 1])) * il;
                data[i + 2] += ((blue  + data[i + 2])) * il;
```

Don't use offsets in an array to represent different types of data. If you can treat your data as the actual type of data it is, that's much easier to read and maintain. If you can format it as `data.red`, `data.green`, and `data.blue`, then you should do it that way.

The second problem is that you're adding a lot more light than I think you intended to. You should only multiply `red`, `green`, and `blue` by `il`, and add them to the existing data in the array. Above you're adding the new color to the existing color, multiplying by the illumination, and then adding it to the existing color again! It should be something like this:

```
                data[i + 0] += red * il;
                data[i + 1] += green * il;
                data[i + 2] += blue * il;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should make your lights look more like real-world lights and fix your blending issues.

If you're looking to speed this up, I'd go with WebGL. It's a lot of work to learn if you don't already know it, but you'll get much better performance. Keep in mind that not every browser supports it, and not every user enables it, so that may make it a bad choice.

Answer (score 4):

Y r vars all 1 ltr?

Is that hard to read? You betchya and so is this code. Just glancing at this, I'm completely assaulted by a large number of single letter, very similar, and practically meaningless variable names.

Words to the wise:

> 1. Make it work.
> 2. Make it right.
> 3. Then, and only then, make it fast.

You've made it work. Now make it *right*. In this case, by "right" I obviously mean you should make this understandable to Joe Maintainer who will have to grok this code without ever having seen it before and without a clue about how it works. Remember, 6 months from now you yourself might as well have never seen the code before.

Some of these I can't even possibly take a stab at, but here are a few replacements that I would make.

- `c` >> `color`
- `rr` >> `red`
- `gg` >> `green`
- `bb` >> `blue`
- `yy` >> `i` (or perhaps something meaningful)
- `xx` >> `j` (or something more meaningful`

Of course, changing `yy` to `i` will force you to give your current `i` variable a sensible name.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I write the vars so small because I want to save bits too but you are right better if I'm asking a question you have to know what does all my vars

Comment: I understand that code size is a performance issue for js, but you really shouldn't worry about it. Just run your code through a minifier as part of your build. It's also important to remember that it's not just about file size, but about how many Http requests the client has to make. [Scott Hanselman has a great article on the topic of optimizing your website.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) Good luck! If you don't get other answers, you may want to go clean up the code and ask another question. =)

Comment: Oh! thanks but I think first is about code improving and later compression (?)

Comment: You can think of compressed (minified) js, css, html as a "compiled" version of the code. It's meant for the machine, not for people. The code you write should be for people. You just compress it with a tool prior to publishing. These tools leave you free to write good code without worrying too much about file sizes and what not.